# LINQ: how to transform list by performing calculations on every element

Tags: c#, linq, sum, transform

I have a class

```
Class MyObject
{
    decimal v1;
    decimal dv1;
    decimal v2;
    decimal dv2;
}
```

and a

```
List<MyObject> ...
```

I need to process every element of the list by adding dv1 to v1 and dv2 to v2
Something like (pseudo-syntax):

```
myList.Transform(o=>o.v1+=o.dv1, o.v2+=o.dv2)
```

How can I do this (obvious my pseudo-syntax doesn't works)?

Thank you

Comment: This is not something you should do with LINQ. LINQ is for doing queries (=read only). You want to mutate state. You can use an simple foreach statement for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the List's ForEach method:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();

// Populate list.

objects.ForEach(obj => {
  obj.v1 += obj.dv1;
  obj.v2 += obj.dv2;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

LINQ is made to get a subset of a given enumeration or to create an enumeration with new types out of an list.

To manipulate a given list, LINQ is not the right tool to manipulate a given list. To do your task you should take a foreach loop like

```
foreach(var item in objects)
{
    item.v1 += obj.dv1;
}
```

What you can do is pre-select, which elements from objects you want by something like this

```
foreach(var item in object.Where(o => o.v1 % 2 == 0))
```

Like others mentioned you could self implement a `ForEach()` extension method, but there is a reason why it doesn't exist:
Take a look at [Erics Blog entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).

Answer (score 3):

LINQ offers ['select' for transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397914.aspx)

```
list.Select( obj => new MyObject(obj.v1 + obj.dv1, obj.dv1, obj.v2 + obj.dv2, obj.dv2))
```

But be aware that the return value is a new list ; the elements of the original list are not modified. No Side effects/State mutation.
If that is your goal, go for select ; else go with the for/for-each as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is typical task for linq, but if you want, you can do this:

```
List<MyClass> objects = GetMyClasses();
Func<Action<MyClas>s, bool> do = (action) => { action(); return true; }
(from o in objects
 where do( o, b=> { b.v1 += b.dv1; b.v2 += b.dv2; } )
 select o).ToArray();
```