# Checking each element of a list and change it (C#)?

Tags: c#, list

how can I check a certain element from a generic list and change it if needed?

something like

```
list.WhatEever(l => l.TheElem == null ? l.TheElem = 1 : 0)
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995516/linq-how-to-transform-list-by-performing-calculations-on-every-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use a method for this, you can use `ForEach`, but only on lists (the call to `ToList` is not needed if `list` is already a `List<T>`):

```
list.ToList().ForEach(l => l.TheElem = l.TheElem == null ? 1 : 0);
```

Personally I would find it more straightforward to just use a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var l in list)
{
    l.TheElem = l.TheElem == null ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This has the benefit on working on any `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just `List<T>`.

Comment: @LukeH: good call, but if it's a value type, I think the compiler will reject the `foreach` construction (modifying `l` will not be allowed).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `l.TheElem = l.TheElem == null ? 1 : 0;` ?

Comment: @dkson: of course! It's a typo, will fix. Thanks for pointing it out.